# Issue In Converting utf8_general_ci to JSON

Tags: php, json, string, utf-8, hebrew

I am storing HEBREW text in MYSQL with **utf8_general_ci** it is stored like **×˜×™×‘ ×˜×™×¨×ª** ×¦ ×

But when I retrieve it and do **json_encode** it converts the **×˜×™×‘ ×˜×™×¨×ª** ×¦ ×  to HEBREW text.

```
{
    "taskdetails": {
        "customerID": "37031",
        "name": "החברה הכלכלית",
        "destination": null,
        "quantity": "0.000000",
        "containerNO": "0",
        "cell": "0000000000",
        "startdate": "29/12/2013 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

But in some cases the JSON string returns **NULL**. Can you see the destination it returns but the actual value is stored in DB as **×˜×™×‘ ×˜×™×¨×ª** ×¦ ×

Any idea whats goes wrong? and help in solving the issues??

My PHP Script:

```
$JSONarray=array(); //Inititlizing JSON
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryExe)){
$JSONarray['customerID'] = $row['AUTO_ID'];
$JSONarray['name'] = $row['Customer_Name'];
$JSONarray['destination'] = $row['Destination'];
$JSONarray['quantity'] = $row['Quantity'];
$JSONarray['containerNO'] = $row['Container_Number'];
$JSONarray['startdate'] = $row['startdate'];
}
//Output the final JSON
echo json_encode(array("taskdetails" => $JSONarray));
```

When I use:

> mysql_set_charset("utf8");

I got the following output:

```
{"taskdetails":{"customerID":"37031","name":"\u00d7\u201d\u00d7\u2014\u00d7\u2018\u00d7\u00a8\u00d7\u201d \u00d7\u201d\u00d7\u203a\u00d7\u0153\u00d7\u203a\u00d7\u0153\u00d7\u2122\u00d7\u00aa \u00d7\u00a2\u00d7\u017e\u00d7\u00a7 \u00d7\u201d\u00d7\u017e\u00d7\u00a2\u00d7\u2122\u00d7\u2122\u00d7\u00a0","destination":"\u00d7\u02dc\u00d7\u2122\u00d7\u2018 \u00d7\u02dc\u00d7\u2122\u00d7\u00a8\u00d7\u00aa \u00d7\u00a6 \u00d7","quantity":"0.000000","containerNO":"0","cell":"013511004211315","startdate":"29\/12\/2013 00:00:00"}}
```

After I check in Jsonlint.com it comes like:

```
{
    "taskdetails": {
        "customerID": "37031",
        "name": "×”×—×‘×¨×” ×”×›×œ×›×œ×™×ª ×¢×ž×§ ×”×ž×¢×™×™× ",
        "destination": "×˜×™×‘ ×˜×™×¨×ª ×¦ ×",
        "quantity": "0.000000",
        "containerNO": "0",
        "cell": "0000000000",
        "startdate": "29/12/2013 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Now every thing goes wrong!!

Other options tried:(Not all at once)

```
mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'", $conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'", $conn);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Also when I check this:

```
  $charset = mysql_client_encoding($con);
  echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
```

OUTPUT:

> The current character set is: latin1

Answer (score 1):

You should set the database connection encoding to UTF-8 when you connect. You seem to be using the deprecated MySQL API, so to set the encoding you need to add this to your program:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: after I use utf8 I am still facing the issue @joni

Comment: Now you get the expected result: the JSON contains the same string you have in the database.  Ideally you should fix the database so that if actually stores Hebrew text as legible Hebrew text, but if you can't or don't want to do that there are workarounds you can use.

Comment: Kindly advice me.. so i can try those to fix the issue.. but converting the whole DB is mearly a big problem.. but i can use this for future datas.. what wil happen for my present data then?? how can i do a work around and idea to change the character??

Comment: A quick fix for the database is converting the column encoding to latin1 and then converting the table to utf8; you can do this with two SQL statements. A workaround that works for 99% of the text is passing it through a character set conversion function, for example `iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $text)`

Comment: It says ERROR : Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string in

Comment: The current character set is: latin1  @joni

Comment: latin1 in MySQL is almost the same as cp1252, but it defines two characters that cp1252 doesn't have. That is why the solution only works for 99% of the text. You should fix the text stored in the database.

Comment: A quick fix for the database is converting the column encoding to latin1 and then converting the table to utf8; ?? I hope it i already the same..

Comment: any help for more explination?